# "No endpoint configuration found in scanned assemblies” for copied NServiceBus project

Tags: nservicebus

I made my NServiceBus solution and it was all working.  I then moved one of the projects to a different solution.

When I run them in that solution I get this error:

> No endpoint configuration found in scanned assemblies. This usually happens when NServiceBus fails to load your assembly contaning IConfigureThisEndpoint.

I have a class in the project I am trying to get running that looks like this:

```
public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Server
{
}
```

I fully copied the folder that contained this project when I moved it to the new solution.  (So this is the exact same class that is in the original and the original worked perfectly.)

I am not sure what to do, so I did a bit of googling and came up on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095043/the-dreaded-no-endpoint-configuration-found-in-scanned-assemblies-nservicebus).

Based on the answer there, I have tried this:

- Make sure that there is a class that implements `IConfigureThisEndpoint`
- Make sure that only one class implements `IConfigureThisEndpoint`
- Make sure that the NServiceBus libraries I am using are .NET 4 libraries
- Make sure that the implementing class is public (see code above)
- I don't do any non-default actions with regards to signing so delay-signing should not be an issue

Any ideas what would cause this error (besides what I have tried) would be great!

**UPDATE:**
I remembered that I had used the Modeler to setup the dependencies in the original project and NuGet to do it in the copied project.

So I went and compared versions.  The Modeler based project was using NServiceBus 2.5.0.1496.  When I used NuGet to upgrade that to NServiceBus 2.6.0.1505 (what I had in my copied project) I started getting the same error (in my original project that had previously worked just fine).

So I copied the working DLLs into my broken project and it all started working.

So I can only conclude that this is a version issue.  Something with how I have set things up (defaults for the Modeler) is not compatible with version 2.6 of NServiceBus.

NuGet does not have history of the same version of NServiceBus as the Modeler tools has.  I think this is an error because NServiceBus packages don't reset the build (last) number.  And there is a NServiceBus version

2.**6**.1496, 
but not a
  2.**5**.1496

like what comes with the modeler (there is a 2.5.0.1490, but close only counts in horseshoes and hand grenades).

So I am going to have to abandon NuGet for NServiceBus (because I need the exact version that is in the Modeler or I have to figure out why I am getting this error.)

If anyone has a better way to deal with this problem I would **LOVE** to hear it.

Comment: Would you mind putting the above in the answer so that we can close this one?

Comment: @AndreasÖhlund - Sure.  I will do it right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remembered that I had used the Modeler to setup the dependencies in the original project and NuGet to do it in the copied project.

So I went and compared versions. The Modeler based project was using NServiceBus 2.5.0.1496. When I used NuGet to upgrade that to NServiceBus 2.6.0.1505 (what I had in my copied project) I started getting the same error (in my original project that had previously worked just fine).

So I copied the working DLLs into my broken project and it all started working.

So I can only conclude that this is a version issue. Something with how I have set things up (defaults for the Modeler) is not compatible with version 2.6 of NServiceBus.

NuGet does not have history of the same version of NServiceBus as the Modeler tools has. I think this is an error because NServiceBus packages don't reset the build (last) number. And there is a NServiceBus version

2.6.1496, but not a
2.5.1496

like what comes with the modeler (there is a 2.5.0.1490, but close only counts in horseshoes and hand grenades).

So I am going to have to abandon NuGet for NServiceBus (because I need the exact version that is in the Modeler or I have to figure out why I am getting this error.)